# Usage of empty array allocation for custom class

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, allocation

Say, we have a class `Car`

```
classdef Car < handle
    properties
        wheels = 4;
    end
    methods
        function obj = Car()
        end
    end
end
```

We can create ten cars like so

```
cars = Car.empty();

for ii = 1:10
    cars(end+1) = Car;
end
```

However, one can make an empty array of cars first

```
>> cars = Car.empty(0,10)

cars = 

  0x10 Car array with properties:

    wheels
```

What I do not understand: If one now puts a single car in it, the array seems to shrink to a single element

```
>> cars(1) = Car

cars = 

  Car with properties:

    wheels: 4
```

So, **does allocating such an empty array make any sense?** What are the use cases?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that your question is not directly related to custom classes - you can do this with any MATLAB variable type. For example,

```
>> a = double.empty(0,10)
a =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-10
```

So your questions are

> What I do not understand: If one now puts a single car in it, the array seems to shrink to a single element

Well no, it has *grown* to a single element. I guess there is an ambiguity here, in that you might expect it to grow not to a 1x1 array but to a 1x10 array, with the other nine elements that weren't directly assigned being set to default (i.e. zero in the case of doubles or other numbers, or to a default element in the case of a custom class). However, I think the only thing to say there is that that's not what MATLAB does.

> does allocating such an empty array make any sense? What are the use cases?

The use cases are very few in general, really just edge cases. The capability of having arrays of with zero-length dimensions is obviously required to be there for consistency, but an array of 0x10 is rarely much different in behaviour from an array of 0x0.

If I have an array that may vary in height but will always be 10 wide, I might predefine it as 0x10 rather than 0x0, just to leave myself a reminder in the code of that fact.

Also note that there are differences in behaviour between `[]` and `double.empty(0,0)`. For example

```
>> a = rand(4,2)
a =
      0.83625      0.19468
      0.58508      0.12698
      0.44332       0.8509
      0.51858       0.3673
>> a(2,:) = []
a =
      0.83625      0.19468
      0.44332       0.8509
      0.51858       0.3673
>> a(2,:) = double.empty(0,0)
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. 
>> a(2,:) = double.empty(0,2)
Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.
```

This is because `= []` is a special piece of MATLAB syntax that is used for deleting rows, rather than literally constructing the empty array and then assigning it. So there's another use case there, i.e. preventing accidental deletion of rows.

Comment: so `<Class>.empty(1,numel(x))` can be replaced by a simple `<Class>.empty()` as MATLAB - as I slowly get to understand - supports indexing empty fields anyway, right? So an array of objects is something like a linked list and there is nothing like preallocation I guess

Comment: I'm not sure how you got those ideas from my answer. First off, `<Class>.empty(1,N)` will error unless `N` is zero, so it's rarely equivalent to `.empty()`. Secondly, although I'm not sure what you mean by "indexing  empty fields", `empty` is not a field, it's a static method of all classes, that creates empty arrays of the class (of various empty dimensions, e.g. 0x0, 0x10, 2x3x0x4x5). Arrays of objects are really nothing like linked lists, and you can absolutely preallocate arrays. But perhaps you mean something different to me by "preallocation".

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem related to object programming but a normal behavior which is more general in Matlab.

For instance:

```
>> a = NaN(0,10);
>> a(1) = 5;
>> a
a =
    5
```

When you define an array of size `0xn` Matlab does not allocate any memory to it, since there is no element. So a call to `empty(0,10)` should not be considered as a pre-allocation.

When you define the first element of the array, you **force** a resizing, and during resizing Matlab always adopts the minimal possible size for the array.

The `empty` syntax is useful to define an array that will be filled by aggregation in a loop with the `end+1` syntax, for instance:

```
a = NaN(0,2);
for i = 1:10
    a(end+1,:) = [i i^2];
end
```

Best,

Comment: Your last example doesn't actually _use_ the `empty` method - and it would work exactly the same even if `a` was preallocated as `NaN(0,0)`. In addition, it would be better practice to preallocate it to `NaN(10,2)` and then fill it with `a(i, :) = `. So although I know what you're saying, I'm not sure it really demonstrates a use case for `empty` as requested by the question.